# In dagger 2, Is it possible to do field injection and constructor injection for the same class?

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

Is it possible to do field injection and constructor injection for the same class ?

For instance : implementation is like

1. activity

   - field injection of fragment.
2. fragment (activityscoped)

   - non parameter constructor injection (downstream )
   - field injection of presenter(Fragmentscoped) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inject constructors, methods, and fields within the same class. Dagger will automatically inject fields and call `@Inject`-annotated methods as part of the construction process.

Comment: @Rakesh: Your edited question is not clear. Are you talking solely about a Fragment? If so, how would constructor injection ever be possible, since Android prescribes exactly what a Fragment constructor must look like?

Comment: @Inject SomeFragment()  that means without any constructor parameters i will inject the fragment to activity.

Comment: As it is non parameterized constructor injection, I've to do field injection for some fields.

Comment: Then...yes. No special rules apply. If you're trying it and having trouble, please ask a separate question.